# How do I delete something from React state that's a queue data structure?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, class, queue, state

I'm trying to create a project that will allow the user to choose between a list of dogs to adopt and a list of cats to adopt. When the user enters one of the lists, they must enter their name in the queue to adopt the dog that has been there the longest (both the people list and the dog/cat list is a queue). Currently, most of the functionality is working. I can add names to the list. All I need to do now is implement a function that allows the user to 'adopt' (delete) the animal on the page. It works fine deleting if from the server, but when I try to set up a method in my React class to set the state so it re-renders automatically, I can't get it working.

Server: https://github.com/thinkful-ei-shark/petful-server-taylor
Client https://github.com/thinkful-ei-shark/petful-client-taylor

```
  adoptDog = () => {
    this.setState({ dogs: [...this.state.dogs.shift()] });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

`.shift` returns the element that was removed, not the array without the first element. Use `.slice` instead to return the array without the first element.

```
adoptDog = () => {
  this.setState({ dogs: this.state.dogs.slice(1) });
};
```

Note that you no longer need the spread (`...`) because slice returns a new array already.

---

Explanation:

Lets say that when the render occurs `this.state.dogs==['fido', 'max', 'timmy']`. You then trigger `adoptDog` expecting to remove `fido` from the array as despite his appalling breath and love of chewing brand-new shoes, he's been adopted. As per usual in React, you don't mutate the array of dogs, but instead assign a new array, which contains the remaining dogs.

Let's look first at what slice does. It returns a new array containing elements `1` through `n` of the source array. I.e. all elements except `0`. `this.state.dogs.slice(1) == ['max', 'timmy']`

Now you've got that new array where the zeroeth element is `'max'` (i.e. he's next up for adoption). So you just assign this new array to the new object containing `dogs` by doing (all in one line):

```
this.setState({ dogs: this.state.dogs.slice(1) });
```

Comment: Great that works! thanks! the only problem is it just removes the dog. I need it to move to the next one in the queue as well.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do with the removed dog? `shift` just removes the first item and moves all the other items left.

Comment: I'd like to just remove it. It's a queue so I want to remove the first dog in the queue and the next one should move to that first position.

Comment: I've added some more explanation to my answer, but basically, this code does exactly what you want I think!